# Trying to read in multiple lines of a file into string array depending on what the line starts with then enter into a map

Tags: java

Why do i only get one entry into the map when i run this code.There is thousands of lines in the file im reading in but it only seems to be getting to the first line and stopping?

```
public class Details {



public Map<String, String> dictionaryWords() throws IOException{
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    Collection<String> words = new TreeSet<String>();
    Map<String,String> m = new TreeMap<String,String>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("dictionary.csv")));
    String line = null;
    String [] word = null;
    String remove = null;
    String nextline = null;
    String getAllLines = "-";
    while ((line = br.readLine())!= null) {


        if (line.startsWith("\"")) {
            getAllLines = line;

            while((nextline = br.readLine())!= null){
                if(!nextline.startsWith("\"")){
                    getAllLines.concat(nextline);
                }else{

                }
                words.add(getAllLines);
                word = getAllLines.split(cvsSplitBy);
                remove = word[0].replace('"', '-');
                m.put(remove.toLowerCase(),Arrays.toString(word));
            }

        }else{

        }




    }
    for (String key : m.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + " " + m.get(key));}
    return m;
}
```

Comment: Your if is flawed. You have line which says if (line starts) with logic. Then in your while you have if line does not start. You can't do the same checks in the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
if(!nextline.startsWith("\""))
{
    getAllLines = getAllLines.concat(nextline);
}
```

Don't forget to reassign "getAllLines" to the return value of the .concat() function.  Since Strings are immutable, the .concat() function returns a new String object, which you do not assign to anything (therefore it is lost).  This leaves you with your original String still stored in "getAllLines" as if the call to .concat() was never made.

Feel Free to use the [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class and the append method, which will likely be much faster than creating new Strings via .concat() thousands of times.

Also: You do not need blank else{} statements.

Comment: Thanks that worked, StringBuilder causes an out of memory error but works with normal strings

Answer (score 0):

In the following part of your code the `nextlines` (2nd ...) are lost in space. They are saved in the variable `nextline` and used as a parameter for `getAllLines.concat`. But the return value of [String::concat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) is not assigned to anything.

```
...
while((nextline = br.readLine())!= null){
    if(!nextline.startsWith("\"")){
        getAllLines.concat(nextline);
    }else{
...
```